The 'import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020', 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext'
import.meta.env.PUBLIC_DASHBOARD_URL
~~~~~~~~~~~
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.524 s
Ran all test suites matching /HomepageHero/i.
(node:18608) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
PS C:\Users\kashi\Documents\CloudFO\cloudfo-marketing-website>
i am facing this import.meta error and actually jest is not supporting it so my test cases are not running properly how can i resolve
